# Snowflake - Error handling the error: String... is too long and would be truncated error

Tags: error-handling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am following the ELT framework for modeling data in a Snowflake warehouse. I am working with a raw table that contains unprocessed data coming from logs.

In this table, there is a UUID field that has been polluted with very long JSON strings. I am working on filtering these JSON strings out. However, I keep running into the error `String... is too long and would be truncated`.

What I've tried:

```
LEN(id_field) < 100
```

and

```
TRY_CAST(id_field as VARCHAR(100))
```

The TRY_CAST method would be perfect if I could specify that the field should be null upon failure but it doesn't seem to behave that way? Parsing the field into a dict doesn't work either as the id values fail due to not having a key.

Comment: Is this happening on COPY INTO? You can truncate them by setting TRUNCATECOLUMNS = TRUE in your copy options. That will truncate the columns to the max width defined for the column. If the string length is greater than 16777216 it will generate an error anyway and you'll have to use ON_ERROR = CONTINUE.

Comment: What about a LEFT(id_field,100)?

Comment: thanks all.. I'm using DBT to manage the transformations.. not sure how much control I have in terms of setting the ON_ERROR option

Comment: try_cast does work in the way you're expecting. For example running this: `select TRY_CAST('adfsdfasdfasdfadf' as VARCHAR(10)) ` returns `NULL`

Answer (score 3):

You can just do something like `LEFT(COLUMN::varchar,100)` that will truncate any value over 100